# Не выполняется программа mpi

Tags: c++, windows, mpi

Добрый вечер. Осваиваю ms mpi. На одном компьютере программа работает нормально.

Код программы:

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "stdlib.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    int numtasks, rank;  
    int rc = MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); 
    if (rc != MPI_SUCCESS) { 
        printf("Error"); 
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc); 
    } 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); 
    cout « "Greeting from Process: " « rank « endl; 
    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

На другом же компьютере  эта программа не работает или ведет себя как то не понятно. Она запускается,  в консоль ничего не выдает и создает процесс mspd которые так и висит пока его не завершишь.

Брандмаузер и Антивирус пробывала отключать, но эффекта никакого. Может кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией? Заранее большое спасибо за ответ

Comment: "smpd", "брандмауэр". Как Вы запускаете программу?

Answer (score 0):

Собери решение, а после через консоль запусти. Запуск производить необходимо через mpiexec -n [число процессов][путь к файлу .exe].
Совет: В дальнейшем делай .bat файл упростит жизнь и обучение))